# Strong maximum principle applied to a complete asymptotically flat manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Pardon me for not typing the following snapshot in MathJax. I'm sorry.

This picture is an excerpt from *Geometric Relativity* by Dan A. Lee. I was wondering about the statement circled in red. How did the author infer from the **strong maximum principle** that $0<u<1$ everywhere? Indeed, we are seeking a positive function $u$ that serves our need in this proof, and since $v$ is not the zero vector, we see that $u$ cannot be $1$ identically. But how was it combined with the principle to give the fact that $u$ is bounded above by $1$? I need some help. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: You know $u$ approaches $1$ at infinity. Assume $u > 1$ somewhere then $u$ needs to have a (strict) local maximum somewhere. This should lead to contradiction with the maximum principle.

Comment: @quarague Thank you, but frustratingly I don't know how to define the limit of $u$ at infinity. Could you tell me its meaning, please?

Comment: Is that defined by $$\lim_{|x|\to\infty}(u\circ\Phi_k^{-1})(x)=1?$$ Here $\Phi_k$ is an asymptotically flat coordinate chart from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: This limit just comes from $u=v+1$ and $v \in W^{2,p}_{-q} \subset L^2$.